# How can I create a link to a URL that includes a computed variable in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, href, window.open

In my Vuejs app, I have a button that opens to a new tab. I need to open a link in a new tab. The link looks like this...

```
<template>
  <div class="header p-4">
    <div class="container-fluid px-2">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            exact-active-class="active"
            :href="getZendeskToken()"
            target="_blank"
          >Community</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NavBar",
  methods: {
    getZendeskToken() {
      axios.get("/zendesk/token").then(
        response => {
          window.open(
            "https://fooWebsite.zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt=" + response.data
          );
        },
        error => {
          store.setErrorMessage("Could not create a JWT", error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

where computeFooParam() executes a server fetch.

The link does not work because computeFooParam() takes time to return a response.

It is possible to have the onclick() attribute of our button call a function that uses window.open() to open a new window. However, this is a popup. Popups are blocked by Firefox by default.

Comment: Hi, can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: try to use asyn/await if you need to wait for response

Comment: Thank you, @Loki. What would that look like in this example? "async" before the  getZendeskToken() declaration? Where should the "await" keyword go?

Comment: await should go in front of your axios request you are making

Comment: you can check more about it here: https://javascript.info/async-await